# Convert Hex to ASCII number on Objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an one hexa decimal number

```
535443326663315634524877795678586b536854535530342f44526a795744716133353942704359697a6b736e446953677171555473
```

I want to convert this number to ASCII format which will look like this

```
STC2fc1V4RHwyVxXkShTSU04/DRjyWDqa359BpCYizksnDiSgqqUTsYUOcHKHNMJOdqR1/TQywpD9a9xhri
```

i have seen solutions here but none of them is useful to me 
[NSString containing hex convert to ascii equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276620/nsstring-containing-hex-convert-to-ascii-equivalent)

i checked here but they give different result. Any help

Comment: have you tried the solution on the other thread? If yes, could you include that code here?

Comment: It seems like you want Base64 encoding.

Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882277/how-to-base64-encode-on-the-iphone

Comment: @robbie_c tried that last one , but result is different what iam getting here in http://www.branah.com/ascii-converter

Comment: NTM1NDQzMzI2NjYzMzE1NjM0NTI0ODc3Nzk1Njc4NTg2YjUzNjg1NDUzNTUzMDM0MmY0NDUyNmE3OTU3NDQ3MTYxMzMzNTM5NDI3MDQzNTk2OTdhNmI3MzZlNDQ2OTUzNjc3MTcxNTU1NDczN  , its coming like this .. it should start with STC

Comment: Ah fair enough, that website seems to just convert one byte of the hex number to one ASCII character, the answer given should work.

Comment: Accept your own answer. It'll help others.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly

```
- (NSString *)stringFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {


    // The hex codes should all be two characters.
    if (([hexString length] % 2) != 0)
        return nil;

    NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [hexString length]; i += 2) {

        NSString *hex = [hexString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
        NSInteger decimalValue = 0;
        sscanf([hex UTF8String], "%x", &decimalValue);
        [string appendFormat:@"%c", decimalValue];
        NSLog(@"string--%@",string);
    }
    _hexString1=string;

    NSLog(@"string ---%@",_hexString1);
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting with `NSData *` you could get the ASCII string this way:

```
NSData *someData = [NSData dataWithHexString:@"ABC123"];

NSString *asciiString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: someData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: That doesn't work out of the box because dataWithHexString is not a function provided by Foundation. You need to add the code from `NSData+HexString.m` (https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471/libsecurity_transform/NSData+HexString.m.auto.html)

Comment: Ok, good point.  Btw why does the link have comment `// Not efficent` ?

Comment: Perhaps because of the use of subroutines such as `strtol()` and the way the source string is indexed. One could access the input as a raw char array instead, which is probably faster, and convert the nibbles thru a table or a few comparisons, additions and shifts. But it's fast enough for most uses as you'll probably not convert millions of these per second.