# How to take third byte from NSData (OBDII)

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, obd-ii

I'm trying to make iOS app which will connect to a car with phone via OBDII (BLE).

I can get a connection with the module and ask about RPM's, and the answers are returned in parts.

First - `010C` (Data used to get RPM's)

then - `41 0C 0A 98 \n \n`

To read RPM's I need only the third and fourth byte (`0A` and `98`). How can I do it?

Part of code from:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"BEF8D6C9-9C21-4C9E-B632-BD58C1009F9F"]])
    {
        //NSLog(@"char %@", characteristic);

        NSData *sensorData = [characteristic value];
        uint8_t *bodyData = (uint16_t *)[sensorData bytes];

        NSLog(@"data bytes %s", bodyData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSData *sensorData = [characteristic value];
const uint8_t* bytes = (const uint8_t*)[sensorData bytes];
uint8_t third = bytes[3];
```

Comment: When I try print third with NSLog(@"new bytes %d", third); result is "new bytes 0"

Answer (score 0):

The way to parse OBD2 answers is to convert the `NSData` to a string and then iterate over the nibbles to compute individual bytes.

Check [Convert Hex to ASCII number on Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827699/convert-hex-to-ascii-number-on-objective-c) for one way to do it.

Alternatively you might want to take a look at https://github.com/mickeyl/LTSupportAutomotive, which already does the heavy lifting.