# Reading NSdata over BLE using LightBlueApplication

Tags: ios, nsdata, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I am trying to read the value that I store in the lightBlue application but the problem is it cannot seems to get the string. It detects that I am reading the data but when I convert the data to a string it outputs @""

```
 -(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
   if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A29"]]){
     if (characteristic.value) {
         NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"The String is %@", stringFromData);
        self.manufacturer = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Manufacturer Name = %@", self.manufacturer);
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: I did some more testing and the NSData sent is in HEX format, how would I convert hex to string? I just NSlogged the Data and it outputted hex values

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code
`NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"The String is %@", stringFromData);`

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, still getting @"" as the value for the string

Comment: if I type "hey there" as the string the output will be 00000000
    0f0e2000  00686579 20746865 726520 which should correspond to "Hey there" but in hex

Comment: it may works. NSMutableString *stringFromData = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
for (int i = 0; i < characteristic.value.length; i++) {
    unsigned char _byte;
    [characteristic.value getBytes:&_byte range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    if (_byte >= 32 && _byte < 127) {
    [stringFromData appendFormat:@"%c", _byte];
    }
}
NSLog(@"The String is %@", stringFromData);

Comment: Reference from here.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276620/nsstring-containing-hex-convert-to-ascii-equivalent]

Comment: Do you mind making that comment an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer since it works! Thanks a lot!