# Convert HEX NSString to an ASCII NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, hex, ascii

I got an NSString containing a **hex value** which I would like to **convert in ASCII**. How can I do this?

```
NSString * hexString = // some value
NSString * asciiString = // ? convert hexString to ASCI somehow
```

---

INCORRECT APPROACH THAT I TRIED:

I tried the following approach that I found on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276620/nsstring-containing-hex-convert-to-ascii-equivalent) but it did not work for me:

```
   NSData *_data = [hexString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableString *_string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    for (int i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
        unsigned char _byte;
        [_data getBytes:&_byte range:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        if (_byte >= 32 && _byte < 127) {
            [_string appendFormat:@"%c", _byte];
        } else {
            [_string appendFormat:@"[%d]", _byte];
        }
    }
    asciiString = _string; // Still shows the same as before..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me:

```
NSString * str = @"312d4555";
NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
int i = 0;
while (i < [str length]){
    NSString * hexChar = [str substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
    int value = 0;

    sscanf([hexChar cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
    [newString appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
    i+=2;
}
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

output is: hello

Comment: "hello" is @"68656c6c6f" in UTF-8